# Creating offset lines

Tags: web-mapping, offset

I have a dataset of coordinates describing central lines of various roads (distanced by +-1m).The goal I would like to achieve is that based on a given coordinate and "traveled" distance I would like to draw a line (google maps/leaflet) that is parallel to the road.

Finding the starting point and the subsequent points can be done with spatial features in my database. The problem I have is calculating the offset coordinates that would create the new line.

In my research I found that GIS software has this baked in but could not get to the mathematical principles/method that I could implement on my web (php, python, sql)